# Center menu CSS

Tags: html, css

how I can center this top menu in css:

[image]

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper_menu_hoz">
    <div class="container_24 ">
        <div class="grid_24 em-area05">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <ul id="nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did u check? text-align:center for nav container... something like `display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;` for nav

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Anju ? that's not a good solution at all ! . RobetD, see my below answer. let me know if it helps

Comment: @Anju No, no, no, no... Robert, please don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a number of ways to do this. it also depends on what code you have on the rest of the items, but  basically this is the way to do it :

see snippet

```css
ul {
  text-align:center;  
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
}
ul > li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  padding:0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_menu_hoz">
    <div class="container_24 ">
        <div class="grid_24 em-area05">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <ul id="nav">
                <li>ITEM</li>
                 <li>ITEM</li>
                  <li>ITEM</li>
              
                   <li>ITEM</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to add `margin: 0 auto;` to nav element, remember that his parent must be on 100% width of the body